# Как сделать, чтобы значения h1, хлебных крошек и title можно было задавать независимо друг от друга для страницы в Битриксе?

Tags: php, битрикс

Здравствуйте! Как сделать, чтобы значения h1, хлебных крошек и title можно было задавать независимо друг от друга для страницы в Битриксе?

```html
<?
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/header.php");
$APPLICATION->SetTitle("Химчистка в Подмосковье");
?>
<div class="services">
<div class="cols2">
    <div class="col1">
        <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:menu", "left", array(
                "ROOT_MENU_TYPE" => "left",
                "MENU_CACHE_TYPE" => "A",
                "MENU_CACHE_TIME" => "3600",
                "MENU_CACHE_USE_GROUPS" => "Y",
                "MENU_CACHE_GET_VARS" => array(),
                "MAX_LEVEL" => "1",
                "CHILD_MENU_TYPE" => "",
                "USE_EXT" => "Y",
                "DELAY" => "N",
            ),
            false
        );?>
    </div>

  <div class="col2 catalog-v2">

<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:main.include", ".default", array(
 "AREA_FILE_SHOW" => "file",
  "PATH" => SITE_DIR."include/templates/spisok_gorodov.php"
 ),
 false,
 array(
 "ACTIVE_COMPONENT" => "Y"
 )
);?>

<div class="col2 catalog-v2">
<div class="cols3">
<div>
 <div style="float: left;padding-top: 3px;margin-right: 10px;">Поделиться в социальных сетях:</div>
                    <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:main.include", ".default", array(
 "AREA_FILE_SHOW" => "file",
  "PATH" => SITE_DIR."include/contacts/share.php"
 ),
 false,
 array(
 "ACTIVE_COMPONENT" => "Y"
 )
);?>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:main.include", ".default", array(
 "AREA_FILE_SHOW" => "file",
  "PATH" => SITE_DIR."include/templates/zakaz_uslugi.php"
 ),
 false,
 array(
 "ACTIVE_COMPONENT" => "Y"
 )
);?>


<div id="2" class="popwindow box_window_in" data-title="" data-height="auto" style="cursor: pointer; height: auto;">
<div class="box_title"></div>
<div class="bw_close">�������</div>
 <div id="comp_bfb51691bea7ceadd7bac530bbbea46a">
<?php $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "innet:form",
    "order_services",
    Array(
        "USE_CAPTCHA" => "Y",
"AJAX_MODE" => "Y",
        "OK_TEXT" => "Спасибо, ваше сообщение принято.",
        "EMAIL_TO" => "email@example.com",
        "REQUIRED_FIELDS" => array(),
        "EVENT_MESSAGE_ID" => array()
    )
);?>
</div></div>
</div>

</div><?require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/footer.php");?>
```

Comment: Хлебных крошек??

Comment: Alex78191 да хлебных крошек и h1, и titile

Comment: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=3400 и $APPLICATION->SetTitle не могут вам никак помочь?